# How to get random item every time a key is pressed?

Tags: python-3.x

My program should get a random name from a list every time a key is pressed, and then delete that name from the list. With the code I have now a random name is selected, but the list is emptied completely.

I have tried both a `for` and a `while` loop, but I'm uncertain as what to use in this situation.

```
x = win.getKey()
while len(members) > 0:
    if x:
        name = random.choice(members)
        members.remove(name)
```

As mentioned above I want to draw a random name and delete that name from the list every time a key is pressed, until the list is empty.

Comment: your key prompt is before the loop, therefore only asking for a key press once and then iterating until the list is empty. you need to put that line _inside_ the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to put your key prompt in the loop to cause the loop to pause and wait for input for each element, otherwise the loop will run to completion and instantly empty the entire list.

```
import random

members = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

while members:
    if win.getKey():
        choice = random.choice(members)
        members.remove(choice)
        print(choice)
```

Output:

```
8
4
2
3
7
6
9
5
1
```

If the list is very large, `remove` is a slow linear operation that needs to inspect each element in the list one by one to find a match. Consider using a fast (amortized) constant time `pop` operation which uses an index to find the target element without searching:

```
import random

members = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

while members:
    if win.getKey():
        choice = members.pop(random.randint(0, len(members) - 1))
        print(choice)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. For now the size of the list is negligible, so I'll use your first answer.